# Communicating between 2 devices connected to the same smartphone hotspot

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, hotspot

My windows tablet wich runs an apache server is connected to my smartphone by activating the wifi hotspot of the phone. I can access the contents of my server by the ip assigned to the tablet over my phone. But when i connect another phone to this network i cant access the server running on the tablet. I am a little confused. Is there a way to access this server by a second device? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**All devices** inside the local network created by your phone **should be able to access** your webserver **using the local ip** of your webserver.

Depending on what you are trying to do you could make your life easier by using [UPnP](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/UPnP) on your router (in this case your phone, for example using a tethering app with UPnP support).

Your windows tablet can then use UPnP to broadcast its local ip throughout the network allowing other devices to access it using a `hostname.local` address. Local ip's might change over time and this method will enable other devices to always connect to your local webserver using the same address.